# Android - automatically scroll within AlertDialog TextView

Tags: android, scroll, textview, android-alertdialog

I am using an AlertDialog to track a logFile which is updating in real time, and need to automatically scroll to the bottom of the view whenever an extra line is added.

I am able to cast the `AlertDialog` to a `TextView` (and e.g. using this TextView alter the text size) but any methods involving scrolling don't work.

**Code:**

```
LogFileView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    String logFile = "/data/data/com.test/test.log";
                    String logFileOutput = getFileOutput(logFile);
                    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setMessage(logFileOutput).show();
                    TextView textView = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    textView.setTextSize(8);
                    textView.scrollTo(0, textView.getLineCount());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

`textView.setTextSize(8);` will alter the text size on display

`textView.scrollTo(0, textView.getLineCount());` will do nothing, and the alert dialog, despite having a scrollbar available, will remain focussed on the first line

**Update 1:**

I see there are a few requests for the dialog creation code/errors in the console output.

Firstly, I am not actually using a separate layout/class to create the dialog. It is applying the default layout associated with (`android.R.id.message`) to an instance of `android.app.AlertDialog` and is only constructed within the onClick method for the onClickListener in the code above.

Based on the feedback I've received so far, the code I've most recently attempted to use looks as follows:

```
LogFileView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                String logFile = "/data/data/com.test/test.log";
                String logFileOutput = getFileOutput(logFile);
                final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setMessage(logFileOutput).show();
                TextView textView = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                textView.setTextSize(8);
                //textView.scrollTo(0, textView.getLineCount());
                textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                textView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.scrollTo(0, textView.getLineCount());
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Secondly, there is nothing appearing in the console when the scroll attempt is made - this simply gets ignored at runtime.

The default layout seemed like it would be fine for my purpose, given it appears like a blank TextView with a scrollbar attached, but I think it may be a sensible next step to use a new custom layout and add a ScrollView and see what happens

Comment: try adding this line to your textview  `TextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

Comment: I've tried this and it still has no effect

Comment: Can you post your alert dialog creation code along with XML, I would like to see

Comment: There is no alert dialog XML, the creation code is contained in the onClick method above:

Answer (score 2):

Use below code. I Tested & verified.

```
    textView.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod() // Add this
    textView.text = "your text"
    textView.post {
        val scrollAmount = textView.layout.getLineTop(textView.lineCount) - textView.height
        textView.scrollTo(0, textView.lineCount)
    }
```

Edit:
Equivalent to java:

```
    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    textView.setText("your text");
    textView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int scrollAmount = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(textView.getLineCount()) - textView.getHeight();
            textView.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've tried combining setting the movement method and using post to wrap the scrolling, but it still has no effect in the dialog. Do you have java equivalent instead of kotlin?

Comment: @nick_j_white Equivalent code to java - check above

Comment: @nick_j_white I tried in dialog, above code is working fine. can you share code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap it with `post` instead of calling directly to `scrollTo`,
something like this:

```
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.scrollTo(0, textView.getLineCount());
    }
});
```

Comment: Should the "s" be "textView" here? I've tried wrapping the scrollTo method inside the Runnable and using post as above, but it's still having no effect

Comment: any errors in the console?
needs to see more code like the layout to get better understand.

Comment: As mentioned above, there is no separate layout for the AlertDialog